# How to read the entire content of satellite assemblies without referring programmatically?

Tags: c#, localization, system.reflection, resourcemanager

I need to be able to read the contents of satellite assembly when its location given along with its culture info. so, i cant add a reference to this assembly at compile time  and i will not know the exact contents of this assembly(i will have to read the entire content). Is there a way to do it ?. like reflection . I have tried with resource manager but i think i cant read the whole satellite assembly content using that.

Something like below is it possible?

```
ResourceManager rm=new ResourceManager();
rm.BaseName="LocationProvidedAtRunTime";
ResourceSet rSet =rm.GetResourceSet("providedCultureInfo, true, true);
List<string> stringIds = new List<string>();
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in rSet )
{
    stringIds .Add((string)entry .Key);
}
```

EDIT:

My requirement is like "Replacing/adding new strings to any satellite assembly when its location and culture info is given"

Thanks,

Comment: What are you trying to do?  There may be a simpler way.

Comment: @Bobson:i am writing a generic tool to update/add some strings in the satellite assembly...

Comment: This information of what strings are changed could be provided in a file